# Can't debug windows odoo, pydev debugger Process finished with exit code -1073740940

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, odoo

My company wants to implement an ERP and we've decided that Odoo is the chosen one.

Odoo server (debian) is running, but we need a development environment in windows which I've already installed,from PyCharm I can Run the odoo server and navigate through the browser and watch the log fill, so I think it works.

But I can't launch in Debug mode, when I try it the message in the console is:

C:\python\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 57805 --file D:/devpython/vodoo/odoo-bin --config=D:\devpython\vodoo\odoo.conf
pydev debugger: process 7072 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 181.4892.64)

Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)

Is there a log for this so I can try to solve the problem? or has anyone encountered the same problem?

the only "weird" thing is that the python.exe path is different from the python.exe in my virtual environment is this a problem? if so, how can I change this configuration? I already set my Run configuration and selected the interpreter in my Virtual environment. when i run the Odoo server I get this:
 (first line): D:\devpython\vodooenv\Scripts\python.exe D:/devpython/vodoo/odoo-bin --config=D:\devpython\vodoo\odoo.conf

Which as I understand means that is running python.exe from my virtual environment, but when I try to debug launches from another python.exe.

Sorry if this is a noob question (I have the feeling it is), but I can't find an answer or a log to know more about the problem... also sorry if my english is not good.

Comment: Yes it’s a problem, PyCharm must use the python.exe of your virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks, so if i understand correctly I have to install all the odoo prerequisites in my main python folder in order to debug ?